# Cannot read property 'range' of null error in CRA 4.0.0

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint, react-scripts, babel-eslint

I have updated Create React App (CRA) from 3.3.0 to 4.0.0, After this update it throws **Can not read property 'range' of null**, I have deleted the node modules and yarn.lock and installed the packages again but it has not resolved.

My Eslint config file

```
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": [
        "prettier", "prettier/react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "prettier", "react"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            2,
            { "SwitchCase": 1 }
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "prettier/prettier": [
            "error",
            {
                "printWidth": 80,
                "tabWidth": 2,
                "useTabs": false,
                "semi": true,
                "singleQuote": true,
                "trailingComma": "all"
            }
        ],
        "arrow-body-style": [
            2,
            "as-needed"
        ],
        "class-methods-use-this": 0,
        "lines-between-class-members": ["error", "always"] ,
        "comma-dangle": [
            2,
            "always-multiline"
        ],
        "import/imports-first": 0,
        "import/newline-after-import": 0,
        "import/no-dynamic-require": 0,
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0,
        "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
        "import/no-webpack-loader-syntax": 0,
        "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
        "max-len": 0,
        "newline-per-chained-call": 0,
        "no-confusing-arrow": 1,
        "no-console": "warn",
        "no-use-before-define": 1,
        "prefer-template": 2
    }
}
```

I have not added babel-eslint in package.json as it is added in CRA by default.

> babel-eslint 10.1.0

Could anyone help with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you also updated eslint and other dev dependencies?